# I am getting result_sheet =result_xlsx.active AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'active' error

Tags: python

```
import os
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

import sys
import csv
import glob
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir

path = r'file path'
files = listdir(path)
result_xlsx = xlsxwriter.Workbook()
result_sheet =result_xlsx.active
```

I am getting "AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'active'" error for the active function after executing my script. I tried upgrading the openpyxl library but still getting same error.

Comment: `active` is a member of `openpyxl` but you are calling `xlsxwriter` in your snippet! Check [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-number-formats)

Comment: It is there. I missed to add the complete syntax here.I am getting it along with it as well